# iPad Simulator View

Tags: ios-simulator

I am looking to increase the size of my iPad simulator when it is fired up on my mac, how would I go about doing this?

The size of the simulator right now is very very small, I can't even see the text on it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the menu, choose Window → Scale → 100%

Comment: scaling to 100% makes the simulator so huge, have to scroll to see full screen